# joomla subscription ecommerce solution

Tags: cms, ecommerce, joomla, shopping-cart, subscription

I am using Joomla and want to implement a subscription based ecommerce solution. I started using VirtueMart and noticed its shortcomings regarding subscription based recurring items.

Turns out Virtuemart can take its own plugins and I found something called SimSu which I don't want to pay for. I feel like I have taken a nuke to a knife fight, as I only need one or two subscription based products on this site. They will be recurring payments.

Is anyone familiar with a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [Akeeba products](http://www.akeebabackup.com) (of [AkeebaBackup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606) fame).

They include [AkeebaSubscriptions](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-subscriptions.html) (for Subscriber Access) and [Akeeba Release System](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-release-system.html) (for managed downloads) we use them on several sites for clients and our product websites.

They are free, well documented and after reading easy to setup.

Comment: There is one tiny thing I don't like, on subscription signup it asks for "Name and Surname" and requires two words to validate this field. I just want it to say name and only require one word to validate. How can I do that

Comment: You would have to modify the code, it's not a requirement we've ever had given tax/receipt laws that we deal with. - cheers

Comment: Great system, but the only thing I'm not so keen on is it doesn't have an auto approve option, therefore you have to manually approve the user.

Comment: @Lodder what do you mean... the whole purpose of it is to add users to groups or other extensions access mechanism, thats what it does automatically. Users subscribe, payment notification is received AS and that triggers the user being added to groups etc.. no human intervention on our behalf. Unless I'm missing what you're meaning.

Comment: @cppl hmm thats odd cause I use it on my website for some commercial extensions and once the user has subscribed and paid, we have to approve it before they are finally added to the usergroup.

Comment: @Lodder Apart from client sites we use it at http://seepeoplesoftware.com with PayPal and it woks automatically always has. In fact it's what Nicholas uses at Akeeba and given the number of sales he has I'm sure he's not approving each one individually. :D

Comment: @cppl: think I know why now. An SSL certificate is needed for the function to work.